# Show loading image while PHP is executing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, jquery-load

I would like to show loading image while the php script is executing. I have read different answers on how to do that but most of them stated that I should have a separate php page. However I am using single page to show the rows, so how can I be able to show loading image?

Example of select query, I am using to fetch the data:

```
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("select * from table where firstname = ?  and id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstname, $id);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

Comment: That query doesn't look like it should take *any* time, really. Is that all it does?

Comment: it takes around 3-4 secs.

Comment: To query one row? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: I got other query also, my bad.

Comment: You need to look at optimizing your queries.  You should NEVER be in the position of having a query that is required to render a page take 3-4 secs, unless you are talking about some backend data analysis type thing that a typical site user wouldn't see.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the majority of cases, you *would* have two pages. The first page, client-side, makes a call to another page, server-side, and shows a pretty spinning thing while it waits. When the server-side page finishes loading (when your query completes) your first page receives a response and then you can hide the pretty spinning thing to let your user know it's finished.

You can use AJAX - in pure Javascript or a lot simpler in jQuery - to dynamically load some data from your PHP page and show a spinning thingy while it waits. I've used jQuery here.

**CSS**

```
#loading_spinner { display:none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="loading_spinner" src="loading-spinner.gif">

<div class="my_update_panel"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#loading_spinner').show();

var post_data = "my_variable="+my_variable;
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/my_php_page.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.my_update_panel').html(data);
//Moved the hide event so it waits to run until the prior event completes
//It hide the spinner immediately, without waiting, until I moved it here
        $('#loading_spinner').hide();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
});
```

**PHP** (my_php_page.php)

```
<?php
// if this page was not called by AJAX, die
if (!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') die('Invalid request');

// get variable sent from client-side page
$my_variable = isset($_POST['my_variable']) ? strip_tags($_POST['my_variable']) :null;

//run some queries, printing some kind of result
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
// echo results
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `var post_data = "my_variable="+my_variable` instead of `var post_data = my_variable` or `var post_data = "foo"`?

Comment: * Why did you not include the declaration of `my_variable`?
* In the PHP, do the results of the SQL query show in the `data` of the AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in PHP itself, you'd have to do something in JavaScript for that. So what you would probably want to do is have JQuery show a loading spinner, then execute an AJAX request to your PHP job, and when you get data back, hide the loading indicator.

Comment: Well this is not fully true it should be possible with php only using progressive rendering (chunked encoding). But it is not something to be recommanded.